# Vector - Call by Reference c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am having problems to define the Methode "add()". What I have learnt to define a function on another sheet until now, is basically:

```
type NameOfClass::function()
{
    // ...
}
```

So now that I try to define the function with a reference parameter (as it is a vector), I have the following declaraation in the class:

```
class Vector
{
    Vector add(const Vector& input) const;
    // ...
};
```

And I am trying to define that function with:

```
Vector* Vector::add(const Vector* input) const
{
    // ...
}
```

I am not sure if my problem is with the "input" or because I am not defining the function in the right way.

Comment: To format code blocks, select the block and press Ctrl+K (or click the `{}` button on the toolbar). I've done it for you here, but this way you'll know for next time.

Comment: You mean you define the function. Nowhere do you actually call it, you just define it after having declared it in the class definition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signatures in declaration and definition need to match exactly.

Declaration:

```
Vector add(const Vector& input) const;
```

Definition:

```
Vector Vector::add(const Vector& input) const
{
   //  ...
}
```